# ExtJS 4.2 > Row Editor Grid > How to cause add button to refresh paging display

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I have the following code for a ExtJS 4.2 grid with row editing enabled. The Add button does not however refresh the paging at the bottom of the grid when a new row is added. Is there any way to accomplish this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Tra nsitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>Branch Awards</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./ext-4.2.0.663/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./ext4.2.0.663/resources/css/ext-all-slate.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./ext-4.2.0.663/examples/shared/example.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./ext-4.2.0.663/ext-all.js"></script>
      <!--
      HTML Multiline comment.
      -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
         Ext.onReady(function()
         {
            Ext.define('Award', {
               extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
               fields: [
                          {name: 'branch_id', type:'int'},
                          'cost_centre', 
                          'branch_name', 
                          'top_60', 
                          'top_30', 
                          'top_10', 
                          {name: 'amount', type: 'float'}
                       ]
            });
            var Awards = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
               model: 'Award',
               autoLoad: true,
               autoSync: true,
               pageSize: 20,
               remoteSort: true,
               proxy: {
                         type: 'ajax',
                         api: {
                                 read: 'award_view.php',
                                 create: 'award_create.php',
                                 update: 'award_update.php',
                                 destroy: 'award_delete.php'
                              },
                         reader: {
                                    type: 'json',
                                    root: 'data',
                                    successProperty: 'success'
                                 },
                         writer: {
                                    type: 'json', 
                                    writeAllFields: true,
                                    allowSingle: false,
                                    encode: false,
                                    root: 'data'
                                 },
                         listeners: {
                                       exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
                                          Ext.MessageBox.show({
                                             title: 'ERROR',
                                             msg: operation.getError(),
                                             icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                                             buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                                          });
                                       }
                                    }
                      }
            });
            var rowEditor = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {clicksToEdit: 2});
            var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
               renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
               frame: true,
               store: Awards,
               width: 550,
               height: 350,
               title: 'Branch Awards',
               selType: 'rowmodel',
               columns: [{
                            text: 'Cost Centre',
                            flex: 2,
                            dataIndex: 'cost_centre',
                            editor: {
                                       xtype: 'textfield',
                                       allowBlank: false
                                    }
                         },
                         {
                            text: 'Branch',
                            flex: 5,
                            dataIndex: 'branch_name',
                            editor: {
                                       xtype: 'textfield',
                                       allowBlank: false
                                    }
                         },
                         {
                            text: 'Top 60',
                            flex: 1,
                            dataIndex: 'top_60',
                            editor: {
                                       xtype: 'textfield',
                                       allowBlank: false
                                    }
                         },
                         {
                            text: 'Top 30',
                            flex: 1,
                            dataIndex: 'top_30',
                            editor: {
                                       xtype: 'textfield',
                                       allowBlank: false
                                    }
                         },
                         {
                            text: 'Top 10',
                            flex: 1,
                            dataIndex: 'top_10',
                            editor: {
                                       xtype: 'textfield',
                                       allowBlank: false
                                    }
                         },
                         {
                            text: 'Amount',
                            flex: 2,
                            dataIndex: 'amount',
                            editor: {
                                       xtype: 'textfield',
                                       allowBlank: false
                                    }
                         }
                        ],
               plugins: rowEditor,
               dockedItems: [
                               {
                                  xtype: 'toolbar',
                                  items: [
                                            {
                                               text: 'Add',
                                               handler: function() {
                                                  rowEditor.cancelEdit();
                                                  // Create a record instance through the ModelManager
                                                  var r = Ext.ModelManager.create({
                                                     cost_centre: '000',
                                                     branch_name: 'New Branch',
                                                     top_60: 'N',
                                                     top_30: 'N',
                                                     top_10: 'N',
                                                     amount: 0
                                                  }, 'Award');
                                                  Awards.insert(0, r);
                                                  rowEditor.startEdit(0, 0);
                                               }
                                             },
                                             {
                                                text: 'Delete',
                                                handler: function() {
                                                   var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
                                                   rowEditor.cancelEdit();
                                                   Awards.remove(sm.getSelection());
                                                   if (Awards.getCount() > 0) {sm.select(0);}
                                                }
                                             }
                                          ]
                               }
                            ],
               bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
                  store: Awards,
                  displayInfo: true,
                  displayMsg: 'Displaying records {0} - {1} of {2}',
                  emptyMsg: "No records to display"
               })
            });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vaguely works, but not very well. First time doesn't work (doesn't show new row or change paging, then second time does work). Consistently fails in this manor.

Comment: Worked when I removed the rowEditor.startEdit(0,0). So you can add it as an answer to get your price.

Comment: Not sure whether it will move my position in the grid with the refresh though.

Comment: Couldn't I use something like store.loadPage(1); but how would I get the current page? Also not sure what effect sorting will have on this.